# Get a property value from an object calling object itsself instead of its property name

Tags: javascript, getter

I wonder if there is a way, in Javascript, to access a property value of an object (properly set with a getter), simply typing its object name without having to type 'object.property'.
What I tried till now is something like this:

```
let person = {
    get () {return this.name + this.lastname},
    name: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
}    
console.log (person);
```

But I always get the entire object instead of the getter property I want.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: `get ()` this needs a name. Consider `get fullname ()`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox He's making up a potential syntax for accessing the object itself rather than a specific property.

Comment: @Barmar ooooo I see.

Comment: You can't do that. The closest you can get is the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method, but it won't be used there.

Comment: `const person = { get x() { return 'something'; } }; (1, eval)('with({ person: person.x }) { console.log(person); }');`

Comment: Maybe what you really need is a `toString()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `.toString()` method, then force the conversion of the object to a string in order to force the `.toString()` method to be called.

Like this:

```js
let person = {
    toString: function() {return this.name + " " + this.lastname},
    name: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
}    
console.log('Person: ' + person);
console.log(''+person);
console.log(person.toString());
console.log(person+'');
```

Notes:

1. The use of the `function` keyword is required in order to preserve the context (can't use arrow function).
2. Doing this: `console.log(person)` will still output the object structure since there is nothing to force the call to `.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: None of the options I'm offering do *exactly* what you're asking for (and what, to my knowledge, cannot be done in JS).

That being said, you can make use of the `toString()` method here, though this only works when the operation you call on `person` requires string coercion.

You can also, at any time, destructure objects so you only get the properties you need.

Both are shown in this example:

```js
let p = {
    toString: function() { return `${this.name} ${this.lastname}` },
    name: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
}

// forcing toString() call
console.log(`${p}`);

// logging the actual object
console.log(p);

// using destructuring
const { name, lastname } = p, person = `${name} ${lastname}`;
console.log(person);
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Person` class along with a getter and destructuring:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, lastname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  
  get person() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.lastname}`;
  }
}

const { person } = new Person('John', 'Doe');

console.log(person);
```

Comment: Only the 'force to string() call method' let me get what I want but it's not a comfortable way to get the value. Thank you anyway!